# Finding frequency of list into second list

Tags: python, csv

If I have two list like I have to find frequency of list1 against list2

```
list1 =[ 'cat','dog','man']
list2 =['cat is sleeping','cat is running','cat and dogs is sleeping ','man dog cat is running']
```

How can I find the frequency of list1 to list2 
I am using regex like

```
for list1 in list1:
        for list2 in list2:
        re.findall(list1,list2)
```

But it is showing error
And I have to save it In CSV Like

Like list1 name is in row and frequency of list2 is in column

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

list1 =[ 'cat','dog','man']
list2 =['cat is sleeping','cat is        running','cat and dogs is sleeping ','man dog cat is running']

for i in list1:
    count=0
    l = []
    for j in list2:
        if i in j:
            count+=1

    print i,count
    l.append(i)
    l.append(str(count))
    print l
    with open('freq.csv', 'a') as writeFile:
        writer = csv.writer(writeFile)
        writer.writerow(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
list1 =[ 'cat','dog','man']
list2 =['cat is sleeping','cat is        running',
        'cat and dogs is sleeping ','man dog cat is running']



res = zip(list1, (map(lambda word: len(list(filter(lambda sen: word in sen, list2))), list1)))

print(dict(res))
```

Will print:

```
{'cat': 4, 'dog': 2, 'man': 1}
```